# Are there any mutants who are well-liked by the public?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Everyone seems to hate mutants, but are there any who are generally well-liked by the public, even when their mutant nature is commonly known?

Comment: This seems very broad. Do you mean the comics, the films, the TV shows?

Answer (score 2):

In the TV series "Spider Man and his Amazing Friends" both Firestar and Ice-Man seem to be well liked by the public at large.

They openly admit to being mutants (and to having been members of the X-Men) on several occasions in the series.